# Ajax request returning error while .net core controller returning 200 Ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am calling .net core action via ajax request. It's not even waiting for the return statement but as soon as I am calling Auth0 management api it's returning error.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]ConnectionCreateRequest model)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _managementApiClient.Connections.CreateAsync(model);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

It's returning error after result statement.

Here is the ajax call:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Connection")',
        contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Connections has been created successfully');
        },
        error: function (result, err) {
            alert(err);
        },
        complete: function () {
            hideLoadingGif();
        }
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `data: model,` directly... _It's returning error after result statement._ what the error says?

Comment: What is the error with the Ajax call?

Comment: just an alert box which says "error"

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, if I pass data: model directly then I am getting null in model argument in my action

Comment: What is the content of `model`?

Comment: just fetching values from form

Comment: Never use `alert` for anything other than simple strings, change your `error:` to `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); }` and see what it says.

Comment: @freedomn-m, by doing this, it's saying "unexpected end of json string"

Comment: ok, so the issue is fixed by returning Json instead of Ok but now there is another thing as soon as it return the response from controller the page gets refresh. Why is that?

Comment: That's a different question, but most likely caused by having your ajax triggered from a button with `<button type='submit'` - change to `<button type='button'`.  If it's from `$("form").on("submit", ...` then add `return false` directly after the ajax call (outside the ajax, inside the handler).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in $.ajax method you didn't specify [dataType](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) property. In this case $.ajax makes an "intelligent guess" based on response content type:

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response.

`Ok()` method in .net core returns empty response without MIME type specified in response header. That's why $.ajax triggers error callback with statusText `"parseerror"`.

The solution is:

- to set $.ajax dataType option to `"text"`, and $ajax will accept empty reponse and trigger success callback
- in .net core to return `Json(true)` or `Json(null)` for successful response, and $.ajax will automatically recognize it as json response and trigger success callback.

Documentation for [$.ajax dataType option](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) for json response:

> As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected if dataType is
> json; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See
> json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Controller is returning Content in the exception Which is a 200 status code result in the terms of IAction Result.

Your controller is catching the exception correctly but still returning a 200 because of the Content return Statement.

Comment: No, I have a debugger on exception. When there is an exception it call the catch block. And as I said there is no exception, it calls return Ok() statement.

Comment: I would mention that in the original question , regardless of this you will still always receive 200 even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @cl0ud you are correct - the js error handler will *not* pickup errors from with the C#.  However, OP *is* getting the error handler, so this is not the cause (though it might be the next question OP asks...)

Comment: @freedomn-m perhaps I misunderstood the question but regardless this confirms that it is impossible for the js error handler to hit in any case as you said.

Comment: well, not in *any* case as OP is (was) getting the error handler - but getting the error handler when there was some other issue (in this case they've specified JSON but not returned JSON so jquery was failing to convert the 200 "(no message)" to JSON and passing to the error handler.